# Using Unity to resolve user control views inside another view

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, prism

I am currently using the MVVM pattern with PRISM in my wpf application and have the Shell, Views, and ViewModels all injecting and tying together.  (As far as I know... this is my first wpf app).  My module definition wires up everything properly.

I have to display a inconsistently sized collection of objects on one of my views and rather than create it all by hand on the backend, I would like to create a new user control and have it bind to an individual data entity so that I can keep it self-cognizant and governing, but those controls need to be added to a grid or panel on my view.  Following the previous examples I decided to walk down the interface + concrete path so as to keep even the smaller pieces flexible.

Firstly, am I going down the right path with this?  In ASP.Net I would create a template for the display and then attach the model.

Second, is there an acceptable way to have my container resolve this "template" user control while I am constructing my main view?

Originally my code looked this this so I want to completely replace it with another xaml:

```
            foreach (var node in nodes) {
                var p = new StackPanel();
                p.DataContext = node;
                p.Children.Add(new Label() { Content = node.Name });
                p.Children.Add(new TextBox() { Text = "" });
                NodesControl.Children.Add(p);
            }
```

Comment: This is what DataTemplates are for.  You can create data templates for each model type in a parent resource (such as in app.xaml) which are then available everywhere in the UI.

Comment: Excellent.  That's a good start as far as splitting out the design and binding for it.  The other half of the question is to have these resolved during runtime.  If I'm giving these templates a View/ViewModel style relation, I'd prefer to have unity resolve these at request.  I may be over-thinking this though which is why I raised the question.  Is it common practice to make DataTemplates into MVVM appropriate pieces?

Comment: You don't need unity at all for the UI.  Any ContentControl/ItemsControl derived container will automatically use the default DataTemplateSelector to locate the appropriate data template.  All you have to do is bind your model to the control's Content or ItemsSource properties and you are done.  As in, full stop.  Stop worrying about it.  Relax, guy.  Ive got a prototype demonstrating this; I'll grab the code and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let DataTemplates do the work for you.

Given a simple window, with the following ViewModel:

```
public sealed class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private object _derper;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (o, e) => { };

    public object Derper
    {
        get { return this._derper; }
        set
        {
            this._derper = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Derper"));
        }
    }

    public ICommand OnDerp { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        OnDerp = new DerpCommand(this);
    }
}
```

We want to show different UI for different values of the property Derper.  This property is set by the DerpCommand:

```
public sealed class DerpCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    private readonly ViewModel _viewModel;
    private int _count = 0;
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _viewModel.Derper = _count % 2 == 0 ?
            (object)new Derp() 
                { Herp = "Derped " + (++_count / 2 + 1) + " times." } :
            new Herp() 
                { Derp = "Herped " + (_count++ / 2 + 1) + " times." };
    }
    public DerpCommand(ViewModel viewModel)
    {

        this._viewModel = viewModel;
    }
}
```

It simply switches the value of `ViewModel.Derper` between instances of `Herp` and `Derp` types based on how many times it runs.  I'll omit the implementation of these models as they are POCOs with a single property.  Dull stuff.

Now, when the `ViewModel.Derper` property is of type `Derp`, we want a nice cornflower blue background with black text foreground displaying the value of the model.  When it is of type `Herp`, we want a black background with white text.  So we create `DataTemplates` for each:

```
<DataTemplate
    DataType="{x:Type t:Derp}">
    <TextBlock
        Padding="50"
        Background="CornflowerBlue"
        Text="{Binding Herp}" />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate
    DataType="{x:Type t:Herp}">
    <TextBlock
        Padding="50"
        Foreground="White"
        Background="Black"
        Text="{Binding Derp}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Notice that in each `DataTemplate` the `DataContext` is the instance of the model of the specified `DataType`.

How do we wire these up?  We don't.  We just specify the area within the UI where we want the appropriate `DataTemplate` to be displayed by adding a `ContentControl` and binding its `Content` property to `ViewModel.Derper`.  Here is the entire UI:

```
<Window
    x:Class="DataTemplateExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:t="clr-namespace:DataTemplateExample"
    Title="DataTemplate example"
    Height="350"
    Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <t:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate
            DataType="{x:Type t:Derp}">
            <TextBlock
                Padding="50"
                Background="CornflowerBlue"
                Text="{Binding Herp}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate
            DataType="{x:Type t:Herp}">
            <TextBlock
                Padding="50"
                Foreground="White"
                Background="Black"
                Text="{Binding Derp}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition
                Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ContentControl
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Content="{Binding Derper}" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="1"
            Command="{Binding OnDerp}">Click me to derp</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And what it looks like:

[image]

After all that, if you still want to use Unity to hook up UI, you can create your own [`DataTemplateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) that uses Unity to look for templates.  Waste of time IMHO.  Go with the flow.